# Color perception vs shade perception demo

Tags: vision, terminology, perception

I can't seem to find one of the best demos I've seen of color vs brightness perception.

It consisted of a rotating animation of earth made of red of bright red points on a dark green background. As the animation plays, the red points slowly get darker while the green background gets brighter. At some point they are of the same brightness (but different colors), which is where something very cool happens; your brain no longer perceives the red points as a 3D object, and they just look like a jumble of points bouncing around the screen. When the red points are darker than the background, the 3D object appears again.

Does anyone know what is this animation called, or where to find it? It's hard to find on google without knowing what to call it.